# how to clean cache JAVA application

Tags: java, http

i have made an application using java.net library to capture the time taken by a webpage to open..example code

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 for(int i=0; i<20; i++ )
  {
   conn.disconnect();
   conn.connect();
   long starTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
   editorPane.setPage(new URL());
   long elasedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - starTime;
   System.out.println(elasedTime);
  }
```

but i am facing a problem, the cache!! 
if i open webpages repeatedly then in some cases it shows time=0 mills...that is certainly not possible, please anybody help me on this!!

Comment: Try `conn.setUseCaches(false);`

Comment: i think you should compare the time taken to load the page by reading the data sent by server(from inputstream). This will help you to get more accurate page load duration.

Comment: @RaviJain: please explain it more...

Comment: using conn.setUseCaches(false); is not helping me...still getting o as value

Comment: currently your program measures only the time taken to connect server , you are not measuring the time taken to read data sent from server(images , html mark-up). Reading response from server takes few milliseconds practically and hence capturing that duration can help you get more accurate results

Comment: @RaviJain: please tell me how to capture that!!

Comment: @rahul : to capture the time taken to receive response(from first bit to last bit) use the code i mentioned in my 2nd comment of my answer.

Comment: @rahul : please mention exactly what code you are using.

Answer (score 2):

`setUseCaches()`, inherited from `URLConnection`, should provide what is required:

```
public void setUseCaches(boolean usecaches)

Sets the value of the useCaches field of this URLConnection to
the specified value. 

Some protocols do caching of documents. Occasionally, it is important to be
able to "tunnel through" and ignore the caches (e.g., the "reload" button in
a browser). If the UseCaches flag on a connection is true, the connection is
allowed to use whatever caches it can. If false, caches are to be ignored.
The default value comes from DefaultUseCaches, which defaults to true.
```

It must be called before the `connect()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can chose not to use any existing cache by setting `conn.setUseCaches(false)`.This might improve the accuracy in calculation.

Answer (score 1):

rahul , there is a huge mistake in your program. Your program is not giving expected results because you have not written it properly , specifically speaking your program is not measuring the time taken by a webpage to open at all.

try this code-->

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 for(int i=0; i<20; i++ )
  {
   long starTime = System.currentTimeMillis();       
   conn.connect();

   JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
   editorPane.setPage(new URL());

   long elasedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - starTime;
   System.out.println(elasedTime);

   conn.disconnect();
  }
```

Strange , no one could notice mistake in your program.

Comment: i did that way cuz i only need to get the time that would be taken in opening the full webpage....thats y i kept conn.connect outta time interval.

Comment: insert these two lines of code -> InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();stream.read(new byte[stream.available()]); after long starTime = System.currentTimeMillis();.

Comment: there is one more thing...i need to capture the time of response too ie time taken by last bit of request to the first bit received...

Comment: and for time of response i used only conn.connect() but this is also giving me issues sometimes its giving me time=0 mills

Answer (score 0):

You can disable caching in `URLConnection` (or `HttpURLConnection`).

See

- [URLConnection.useCaches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#useCaches)
- [URLConnection.setUseCaches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#useCaches)
- [URLConnection.setDefaultUseCaches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setUseCaches%28boolean%29).